# GetAssemblies is never called in IAassembliesResolver

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, assemblyresolve

Currently I try to override the assembly resolving in ASP.Net WebApi 2.  Overrideing:

```
var resolver = new ExtendedAssemblyResolver(new[] { dynAsm });

// Add a list of dynamically loaded assemblies
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), resolver);
```

The resolver looks like this:

```
public class ExtendedAssemblyResolver : DefaultAssembliesResolver
{
    private string[] dynamicAssemblies;

    public ExtendedAssemblyResolver(string[] dynamicAssemblies)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        this.dynamicAssemblies = dynamicAssemblies;
    }

    public ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        var baseAssemblies = base.GetAssemblies();
        var assemblies = new List<Assembly>(baseAssemblies);

        if (dynamicAssemblies != null)
        {
            foreach (var asm in dynamicAssemblies)
            {
                var controllersAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(asm);
                baseAssemblies.Add(controllersAssembly);
            }
        }

        return baseAssemblies;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that `GetAssemblies` is never called.

I've also tried to replace the resolver in my `Startup` class, but this does not help either:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    // Configure Web API for self-host. 
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    // -- here
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't you need an override for `GetAssemblies`? `public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies`

Comment: @heinzbeinz oh man, if that's the problem, I quit for today :D Thanks, just overseen the nice visual studio hint :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the override

```
public class ExtendedAssemblyResolver : DefaultAssembliesResolver
{
    private string[] dynamicAssemblies;

    public ExtendedAssemblyResolver(string[] dynamicAssemblies)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        this.dynamicAssemblies = dynamicAssemblies;
    }

    public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        var baseAssemblies = base.GetAssemblies();
        var assemblies = new List<Assembly>(baseAssemblies);

        if (dynamicAssemblies != null)
        {
            foreach (var asm in dynamicAssemblies)
            {
                var controllersAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(asm);
                baseAssemblies.Add(controllersAssembly);
            }
        }

        return baseAssemblies;
    }
}
```